# Does a Silverlight <Line> need Width and Height defined?

Tags: silverlight-3.0, drawing

It seems that a  won't be visible unless a height and width is specified.  Is this true?

This seems rather tedious.  Couldn't the bounds of the line imply the correct width and height?

```
    <Canvas Height="200" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Beige">
        <!-- This is visible -->
        <Line X1="20" Y1="40" X2="70" Y2="90"
              Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4" Height="100" Width="100" />

        <!-- This is not visible -->
        <Line X1="10" Y1="10" X2="50" Y2="50"
              Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4"/>
    </Canvas>
```

(I'm using Silverlight 3.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can use one of this templates to define coordinates:

1. X1, X2, Y1, Y2
2. Canvas.Left, Canvas.Top, Width, Height.

If you use them together, CLR may sometimes show your controls wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In SL 4, MS shows examples of [mixing X1, X2, Y1, Y2 with Canvas.Left](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189073%28VS.95%29.aspx)

In my own experience, with Visual Studio 2010, in order to see the line in the designer view, I had to set non zero width and height, while also using X,Y to set the line within that space.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the line is drawn at a point (X1, Y1) relative to the Canvas.Left, Canvas.Top of the Line element. So not specifying the Canvas.Left, Canvas.Top means that the line is actually drawn at the point (X1, Y1).

It's like the control dimensions (or the drawing surface of the line) is determined by the Canvas.Left, Canvas.Top, Width, Height and the actual line is render by (X1, Y1) and (X2, Y2) relative to Canvas.Left, Canvas.Top.

The RotateTransform uses the Canvas.Left, Canvas.Top values (unless another Center is specified) and not the X1 etc values. So any transforms on the line may not work as expected if those values differ.

Answer (score 0):

I have silverlight 4, and I resolved the problem specifing the canvas width, canvas height, x1, x2, y1, y2.